# Is it possible to automatically generate a css class while defining it in the .jsx file?

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, reactjs

I am using css module for my React app but I can't remember the class names that i define so i have to check the class names again and again.
Is there any vscode extension or way to generate css classes  automatically   in the `Style.css` file?
So if i create a class like :

```
<div>className={Style.btn}<div/>
```

Then it will automatically generate a  `.btn` class in my style sheet which i imported i.e.

```
import Style from "./Style.module.css";
```

We can assign some initial value like  `color:"" ;` to that class and  we can edit it later.

or we can use a shortcut key so that a mini window will pop up and we will assign some css properties to that class like this
[sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R8Ew4.png)

Or is there any way to get suggestions of the class names  in the css file that i define in the `.jsx` file ?

Comment: Are you the same person who asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68060055/is-there-any-way-to-automatically-create-css-classes)?

Comment: why not create needed classes manually for your specific use case and reuse them everywhere in your app. I may not have the full picture, but it looks like you have a bad UI/UX organisation and you will eventually drown in code smell. If you want to follow your idea, it is possible to create macro/shortcuts/scripts in your IDE to do whatever you want.